# HOW TO solve "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'". I have tried to reinstall 'requests', but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I tried to reinstall `requests` module and that didn't help:

(C:\Users\user\Anaconda3) `C:\Users\user>Desktop\receipt.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\receipt.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

(C:\Users\user\Anaconda3) `C:\Users\user>pip uninstall requests`

```
Uninstalling requests-2.18.4:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests-2.18.4.dist-info\*
    c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\*
Proceed (y/n)? \y
Your response ('\\y') was not one of the expected responses: y, n
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled requests-2.18.4
```

(C:\Users\user\Anaconda3) `C:\Users\user>pip install requests`

```
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/df/50aa1999ab9bde74656c2919d9c0c085fd2b3775fd3eca826012bef76d8c/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2017.7.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.6)
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.18.4
```

(C:\Users\user\Anaconda3) `C:\Users\user>Desktop\receipt.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\receipt.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

---

receipt.py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://invoice.etax.nat.gov.tw/'
html=requests.get(url)
html.encoding='UTF-8'
sp=BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')

title1=sp.select('#area1')
title2=title1[0].find_all('h2')
print(title2[1].text,"Winning Numbers\n")


prize1=sp.find_all('span',{'id':'newFirstPrize'})
print("number:",prize1[0].text)


prize2=sp.find_all("span",{'class':'t18Red'})
print("\n Special Prize：\n",prize2[0].text)

prize3=sp.find_all("span",{'class':'t18Red'})
print("\n Grand Prize：\n",prize3[1].text)

prize4=sp.find_all('span',{'id':'newAddSixPrize'})
print("\n Additional Sixth Prize：\n",prize4[0].text)

input("Press <enter>")
```

Comment: could you post the python files inside the directory containing your receipt.py